# How to sanitize Java object with OWASP encoder?

Tags: java, sanitization, owasp, checkmarx

To escape from Cross-Site-Scripting attack i have to sanitize/validate java object that is coming from RequestBody. Can i make use of Encoder (from OWASP) to encode the entire java object. It seems that the Encoder will encode only the strings and cant accept objects. I have the similar issue many places wherein I should to handle this issue.

Is there any way to do sanitize for whole object for avoiding cross site script issue?

Comment: What does your object contain?

Comment: And also, in what manner is it returned to the client side?

Comment: This object contains several other properties includes list, object, Integers and Strings. The same input will be returned to the client by adding few more property values.

Comment: How did you fixed this?

Answer (score 1):

As you noticed, sanitization of input to prevent XSS (Cross Site Scripting) is only relevant for strings. Encoding other types is either impossible or meaningless.

To understand it better, you need to actually understand the mechanism and attack vector of an XSS. I suggest starting here: [OWASP XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS))

To solve your problem, it would make sense to create a custom method that after getting the object from the request, sanitizes it by going over all its strings (don't forget strings in lists and other data structures) and encode them using the OWASP encoder.

Good luck!